# Extract domain from email and check against another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a tableA with email address for which I want to find those that doesn't exist in tableB

```
 Select distinct(right(email, length(email)-INSTR(email, '@')) as domain from table1 as t1
    inner join tableB  as t2
on t1.domain = t2.domain
where t2.domain is NULL
```

Since `t1.domain` isn't a column I cannot find a way to compare.
If I want to check the whole database for emails that doesn't exist in tableB, how do I do this?

Example
table 1                                 table 2

```
email             name          domain, ...
xyz@gmail.com     Tim           yahoo.com
abc@yahoo.com     Jim           msn.com
ghi@outlook.co.uk Kim           gmail.com
hell@amazon.com   Jeff
```

Output

```
domain
outlook.co.uk
amazon.com
```

Output domains from table1 aren't present on table2

Comment: so you want all domain from t1 that are NULL? please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  and provide as [mre]

Comment: I want all the domains from table1 that aren't on table2. I added examples

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, '[^@]+$') FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE domain = REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, '[^@]+$'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use substing_index and a subselect

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `email` VARCHAR(21),
>   `name` VARCHAR(9)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`email`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('xyz@gmail.com', 'Tim'),
>   ('abc@yahoo.com', 'Jim'),
>   ('ghi@outlook.co.uk', 'Kim'),
>   ('hell@amazon.com', 'Jeff');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2 (
>   `domain` VARCHAR(9)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table2 VALUES('yahoo.com'),('msn.com'),('gmail.com')
> ```

> ```
> Select t1.*,SUBSTRING_INDEX( `email`, "@", -1) as domain 
> from table1 as t1
> HAVING domain NOT IN (SELECT `domain` FROM table2)
> ```
>
> ```
> email             | name | domain       
> :---------------- | :--- | :------------
> ghi@outlook.co.uk | Kim  | outlook.co.uk
> hell@amazon.com   | Jeff | amazon.com
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c794d7e9f476f060b2643fe8fc32f421)*